# Factor analysis structured with a dependent variable (not independent variable)

Tags: categorical-data, independence

A model from the social sciences has been suggested that income inequality (as a dependent variable) "causes" a range of downstream independent variables including teenage fertility, obesity etc. especially as this applies to the subset of nations that are transitioning to a post-economic style of consciousness. These variables were standardized for all included nations and then added together to form factor scores. these factor scores were reported to strongly correlate with income inequality. At first I thought that factor analysis could be easily applied with the independent variables (teenage fertility, etc.) included in a matrix on the left hand side of the equation. A factor structure could then be worked out.

My suspicion is that this is merely a way of restating Spearman's law of the indifference of the indicator. The variables (teenage fertility ...) can all be understood as g loaded tests that people are presented in their lives and respond (or not) to. Life is an intelligence test. If these are the test items one would expect that a general factor (g) should emerge as the first factor with a loading ~ 0.40. This has been repeatedly demonstrated. Any citations for psychometric research with a similar setup as what I have described above would be appreciated.

I found it interesting to reinterpret by transposing the data set in order to develop an understanding of how nations would correlate with each other (I think this is referred to as a Q analysis). In this frame of reference one is not considering correlation of factors (e.g., teenage fertility and obesity considered row by row within nations, but instead row by row by indicator (e.g., American teenage fertility and Asian teenage fertility etc.).

However,it is not entirely clear to me whether applying factor analysis is even the correct approach for my dataset. I could just sit back and let the data reduction happen with the standardization of the indicators and then summing them into a z score. All that is left is the z score and income inequality which has reduced the problem down to a simple linear regression. It would be nice to be able to have factor loadings for each indicator and then weight the z scores to a proper zscore. I realize that social science datasets are probably best avoided when applying factor analysis to these problems; they likely result in more confusion than clarity. It is true I am quite confused about this myself. Help! However, given the clear parallel to intelligence tests, I think it is worthwhile to explore this further.

[image: 3D Quadratic Scatter of Indicator Score(ex IQ) modeled by GINI and IQ.]

Comment: It's not clear to me that this is a statistics question, and therefore appropriate for this site. If it is a stats question, the substantive information and theory is making it hard for me to extract the statistical question.

Comment: From the question: 'income inequality (as a dependent variable) "causes" a range of downstream independent variables"'. Hang on, is income inequality, the DV, a cause? So a predictor? I'm confused.

Comment: You seem to be assigning intelligence to countries. This is rather unusual and puts you at risk of the ecological fallacy.

Comment: Jeremy, thank you very much for replying. Yes, it is confusing. Applying statistics to social science does seem like a hopelessly flawed idea to me as well. After seeing such pseudo-statistical ideas, I would have typically walked away unobtrusively and then ran as fast and as far as possible. The model that tries to explain the downstream social effects of income inequality is not of my making. I do not think that I could have thought up such confusion. I will do my best with what is given. However, there is a body of evidence emerging that does include the concept of national IQ.

Comment: This is as clear as I can describe it for now:  f(y1, y2,y3,...y10) = x1      Roughly the proposed model is the dependent variables (the ys) are linearly weighted and are equated to the one independent variable (x1--- here income inequality). I had thought of it with the xs and ys interchanged and the factor analysis did appear to produce useful insights into the relationships of the variables. By simply adding together the z scores of the ys the equation on the left hand side disappeared and all we are left with is zY = ax1 +b: a linear regression. There is psychometric logic to this.

Comment: Very very exciting! I have been finding so many useful tools to help me. I stumbled unto these 3d  scatter plots and they greatly help one visualize 3d relationships. They also give an intuitive feel for how the fits change with different models. I will be very interested to see whether they have extended 3d ideas to factor analysis.